# how to modify the handler/delegate design pattern

Tags: c#

Suppose you are designing an application that uses handlers to deal with particular abstractions. What would be the correct design pattern if the handlers themselves should provide the same functionality, but in particular cases might have to provide slightly more functionality dependent on some set of logic that stems from the parent class?

```
class site
{
    searchhandler ha = new searchhandler();

    void search()
    {
        ha.search();
    }
}

class searchhandler()
{
    public void search()
    {
        //do work
    }
}

site google = new site();
site yahoo = new site();
site bing = new site();


google.search();
yahoo.search();
bing.search();
```

In other words, based on the code above, suppose that i needed to modify bing.search() at the handler level, so that its instance of searchhandler.search() would have to be overridden somehow. What would be the appropriate design pattern to implement this approach?

Comment: Interfaces? I'm not sure exactly what you mean.

Comment: `You are designing an application that uses handlers to deal with particular abstractions. What would be the correct design pattern?...` You did not provide enough information for us to help you. In fact, you did not provide ANY information, since this phrase does not provide troubleshooting value. Guess why? Because **every** application uses handlers to deal with particular abstractions.

Comment: You could create a new `Bing` class that inherits from `Site` and overrides `Search` perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your problem, you can achieve what you want if you follow this demo architecture. Define interfaces and classes as shown below.

```
public interface ISearchEngine
{
    void Search();
}

public class Site
{
    ISearchEngine searchHandler = null;

    public Site(ISearchEngine searchHandler )
    {
        this.searchHandler = searchHandler;
    }

    public void DoSearch()
    {
        searchHandler.Search();
    }
}

public class GoogleSearch : ISearchEngine
{
    public virtual void Search()
    {
        Console.Write("Google Search.");
    }
}

public class YahooSearch : ISearchEngine
{
    public virtual void Search()
    {
        Console.Write("Yahoo Search.");
    }
}

public class BingSearch : ISearchEngine
{
    public virtual void Search()
    {
        Console.Write("Bing Search.");
    }
}

public class BingSearchV1 : BingSearch
{
    public override void Search()
    {
        Console.Write("Bing V1 Search.");
    }
}
```

and you can use it as follows...

```
Site google = new Site(new GoogleSearch());
Site yahoo = new Site(new YahooSearch());
Site bing = new Site(new BingSearchV1());
google.DoSearch();
yahoo.DoSearch();
bing.DoSearch();
```

I hope you got your answer.

Comment: yes this was my question, and the approach i initially was going to take but it seemed strange to have to define a custom handler for special situations when only one aspect of it needed to be changed